# How to make labels appear at a different scale than features' scale in Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, labeling, style, scale, display

I'm using Geoserver 2.6.2.

I need to display land parcels and their references (a number). I have specified a `maxscaledenominator` for the features (polygons) but I don't want references to appear at such a scale for it will be a nonsense (parcels appear very small and dense so that no additional information is needing on the map). Is it possible to specify a `maxscaledenominator` for labels as well?

Here is an extract of my code:

```
<UserStyle>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
            <MaxScaleDenominator>20000</MaxScaleDenominator>
            <PolygonSymbolizer>
                <Stroke>
                    <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
            </PolygonSymbolizer>
            <TextSymbolizer>
                <Geometry>
                    <ogc:Function name="centroid">
                        <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                    </ogc:Function>
                </Geometry>
                <Label>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>reference</ogc:PropertyName>
                </Label>
                <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
            </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a `Rule` can have a scale denominator, but that's fine as you can have as many `Rule`s as you need. So just split your labels into another rule with its own `MaxScaleDenominator`, like this:

```
<UserStyle>
    <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
            <MaxScaleDenominator>20000</MaxScaleDenominator>
            <PolygonSymbolizer>
                <Stroke>
                    <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
                    <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
                </Stroke>
            </PolygonSymbolizer>
         </Rule>
         <Rule>
            <MaxScaleDenominator>5000</MaxScaleDenominator>
            <TextSymbolizer>
                <Geometry>
                    <ogc:Function name="centroid">
                        <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
                    </ogc:Function>
                </Geometry>
                <Label>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>reference</ogc:PropertyName>
                </Label>
                <Fill>
                    <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
            </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
    </FeatureTypeStyle>
</UserStyle>
```

Comment: The issue with your proposal is that the GeoServer style legend gets overloaded as one item is created per rule... Any idea on how to keep only features rules within legend?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's too late, but you can see this 
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/textsymbolizer.html#scalable-font-size
When you are in a determinate scale you put font 0 is you dont want to see

```
       <CssParameter name="font-size">
           <ogc:Function name="Categorize">
             <!-- Value to transform -->
             <ogc:Function name="env">
               <ogc:Literal>wms_scale_denominator</ogc:Literal>
             </ogc:Function>
             <ogc:Literal>12</ogc:Literal>
             <ogc:Literal>999999</ogc:Literal>
             <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
             <ogc:Literal>1000000</ogc:Literal>
             <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
           </ogc:Function>
         </CssParameter>
```